# Laravel 5.1 Searching encrypt not working for me

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5.1, crypt

I'm working on this model with name field encrypted using Crypt class, i can display data into decrypted in view. but when searching for the value in the model that is encrypted. my controller returns null.

//heres my code: validator model.
//validator->validate($code)

```
return $this->validator
            ->where('name', '=', $code)
            ->where('date_end', '>=', $dateToday)
            ->where('availability', '=' ,0)
            ->first();
```

//and note, im using traits for auto encryption and decryption for my model

```
trait Encryptable {

    public function getAttribute($key){
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if(in_array($key, $this->encryptable)){
             $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if(in_array($key, $this->encryptable)){
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }

}
```

please help.